# Can you specific pod deployment order with Helm?

Tags: deployment, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-helm

Is it possible with Helm to say I want pod x to be deployed before I start deploying pod y?

The context here is I would like to have the pod with the database in it deployed before the server pod is started up that is going to add test data to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can always keep them in order in your files - Helm will respect that.